# Using virtual users with pam gives error

Tags: vsftpd, pam

I get this error from PAM using mysql with vsftpd:

PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_mysql.so): /lib/security/pam_mysql.so: undefined symbol: make_scrambled_password

From what I understand libmysqlclient.so.18 is the [problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=709534) at least since libmysqlclient.so.16. It seems that the function used in pam called make_scrambled_password is deprecated.

At least I think that is the problem. How can I go about getting around this? I guess I can hack the code (pam_mysql.c) to find a replacement for that function but I'm hoping for a simpler option.

I'm using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dumb luck I found an rpm with a patch: http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/6/x86_64/pam_mysql-0.7-0.12.rc1.el6.x86_64.html

I downloaded the source RPM and patched my version of PAM.

```
patch < pam_mysql-0.7RC1-scrambled.patch
```

This assumes you are in the Pam source directory where pam_mysql.c exists.

Recompile pam and your set. Phew.

Comment: Tom, sorry for bumping year old thread but does this patch get rid of make_scrambled_password? And how does it work with updates you apply to your system later?